# Promise<any> chaining in Ionic2 SQLite native plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am new to Javascript promises, and I am not being able to do a proper chaining.

I am using the [native SQLite Ionic2 plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/) that wraps the [cordova sqlite plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) in a promise-like API. I want to wait for an SQL query to resolve and then use the result set to get the data, since I am executing a SELECT clause. The SQLite example, along with my code, is as follows:

```
  [...]
  executeQuery(query: string, params: any){
    let db = new SQLite();
    return db.openDatabase({
      name: 'applicationData.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then(() => {
      db.executeSql(query, params).then((resultSet) => {
        return resultSet;
      }, (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to execute sql: ', err);
      });
    }, (err) =>{
      console.error('Unable to open database: ', err);
    });
  }
    
  getConfig(){
    let query = 'SELECT * from configuration';
    this.executeQuery(query, []).then((resultSet) => {
      resultSet.rows.item(0);
    }, (err) => {
    
    });
  }
  [...]
```

And I am getting:

> Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'void'.
>
> [19:13:19]  transpile failed
>
> [19:13:19]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
>
> [19:13:19]  Error: Error

```
L23:  this.executeQuery(query, []).then((resultSet) => {
L24:    resultSet.rows.item(0);
L25:  }, (err) => {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `db.executeSql` call inside your `executeQuery` method, otherwise your `Promise` just returns `void` like the transpiler says:

```
executeQuery(query: string, params: any){
    let db = new SQLite();
    return db.openDatabase({
        name: 'applicationData.db',
        location: 'default'
    }).then(() => {
        //here
        return db.executeSql(query, params).then((resultSet) => {
            return resultSet;
        }, (err) => {
            console.error('Unable to execute sql: ', err);
        });
    }, (err) =>{
        console.error('Unable to open database: ', err);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the problem. I am having a hard time understanding promises logic.